# How to expose flask app builder security login api with out login. Currently swagger docs showing only when user logged in

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-security, flask-appbuilder

I am trying to extend the flask app builder with adding new interfaces and exposing api's only when logged in with token.

As per the existing FAB, we could see swagger api's only when user logged in. So would like to expose login api before login so that front-end can call login api. Right now its throwing access denied.

Let me know if we have any other solution to do the same.

http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1 is throwing access denied error

Answer (score 0):

Spent several days to find the way. Just only add two permission `can get OpenApi` and `can show SwaggerView` to **Public** user.

[(Image on Apache Superset App)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h3sJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).